# storage of android app data so that data couldnot be erased

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

if we store data in sqllite database in android, then data will get erased if this apk is installed in another phone.

> Then how does offline dictionary apps store data which is accessed by everyone having the app.

Comment: "if we store data in sqllite database in android, then data will get erased if this apk is installed in another phone" -- um, no. User #2 installing the app, by default, has no impact on the data on User #1's copy of the app on a separate device.

Comment: what do you mean by web services?

Comment: google it you will come to know

Answer (score 1):

I might not fully understand this question, but if you are storing data in a SQLite database, it will only be persisted on that device; it has nothing to do with the apk or installing the apk on another device. The application will attempt to create a new database on every device it is installed.

Installing the apk on another device will not copy the database from one device to another.